ColorManager. CreateDevice from command line. Object created but disappears
I'm trying to create a display object for ColorManager (I have none because there isn't any programs/daemons running for that) from command line. I've tryed all the command I know:
dbus-send --system --print-reply --type=method_call --dest=org.freedesktop.ColorManager /org/freedesktop/ColorManager org.freedesktop.ColorManager.CreateDevice string:"MyMonitor" string:"temp" dict:string:string:"Colorspace","RGB","Kind","display"

and
busctl call --system org.freedesktop.ColorManager /org/freedesktop/ColorManager org.freedesktop.ColorManager CreateDevice ssa{ss} "mymoniotr" "temp" 2 "Colorspace" "RGB" "Kind" "display"

and
gdbus call --system --dest org.freedesktop.ColorManager --object-path /org/freedesktop/ColorManager --method org.freedesktop.ColorManager.CreateDevice "mymonitor", "temp" '{"Colorspace":"RGB" , "Kind":"display"}'

The object is been created everytime (I got the return message) but I cannot find it, it disappears. Using d-feet, I can create the object successfully.
Something wrong with the command lines?

Some D-Bus services are designed so that the lifetime of certain objects is tied to the lifetime of the D-Bus client, and as soon as the client disconnects from the bus, its resources are cleaned up (much like e.g. the OS would close all open files when a program exits).
Indeed that's what colord does when you specify "temp" as the 'scope' parameter. The default seems to be to create a normal memory-persistent object, but CD_OBJECT_SCOPE_TEMP makes it explicitly tied to the lifetime of the client and removed on disconnect. Similarly with D-Feet (which has now become D-Spy), the object would disappear when you closed the program.
In short, you need to write a daemon.

Yes, you are right. I've written a daemon in python using glib and the device doesn't disappear anymore.
